# If any column has NULL value in oracle forms then how the next row to be inserted

Tags: sql, oracleforms, oraclereports

If any column has NULL value in oracle forms then how the next row to be inserted.

```
empID   city
1001    NYC
1002    DC
1003    CA
1004    NULL
1005    LA
1006    PL
```

Here in 4th column NULL value is there in Oracle forms.If we insert the next value then it revert back to 4th row means **LA** shift to 4th row & **PL** shift to 5th row.How can we done it that inserted rows shift up in Oracle forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `lag( . . . ignore nulls)`:

```
select empID,
       coalesce(city, lag(city ignore nulls) over (order by empID)) as city
from t;
```

If you actually want an update, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set city = (select max(t2.city) keep (dense_rank first order by t2.empID desc)
                from t t2
                where t2.empID < t.empId
               )
    where city is null;
```